# What game engine should I use for a game in non-euclidean space?

Tags: game-development, geometry

I am interested in making a game in elliptical space. Basically that means that when you're standing still in this game and look around, you will see a regular three dimensional space. Then when you start to move around things won't move the way you expect them to. I won't be able to represent the world with regular coordinates, but in order to show the player the world I will project it into the regular euclidean space that they are used to and show them that projection.

I want to know what game engines may be good for this. I've never made a game before, but I predict that something very high level like Unity or Unreal would be too focused on complicated things that would be hard too adjust to this idea. On the other hand, I'm more of a theoretical computer science guy than a practical computer science guy, so I don't want something too low level where I'll basically be starting from scratch. Any idea where I should start?